# How to load value from database when the html element is called/show up

Tags: jquery, laravel

so I have a field to choose the size and fill the stock input, and I add jquery so the user can add those field according to the needs. But the problem is when I click the button to add those fields the size value data from the database is not loaded. how to display data from the database along with the appearance of those fields? I need to load these value {{ $size['name'] }} and {{ $size['id'] }}

Here is my script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var maxField = 10; //Input fields increment limitation
var addButton = $('.add_button'); //Add button selector
var wrapper = $('.field_wrapper'); //Input field wrapper
var fieldHTML = '<div id="fieldExtra"><div class="form-group"><label class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 control-label"></label><div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12"><select class="form-control" name="color" id="color" required><option>Choose Size</option>@foreach ($sizes as $size)<option value="**{{ $size[\'id\'] }}**">**{{ $size[\'name\'] }}**</option>@endforeach</select></div><div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="stock" id="stock" placeholder="10" required></div><div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus grey" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:20px;top:6px;"></span></a></div></div><!-- form-group --></div>'; //New input field html
        var x = 1; //Initial field counter is 1

        //Once add button is clicked
        $(addButton).click(function(){
            //Check maximum number of input fields
            if(x < maxField){
                x++; //Increment field counter
                $(wrapper).append(fieldHTML); //Add field html
            }
        });

        //Once remove button is clicked
        $(wrapper).on('click', '.remove_button', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#fieldExtra").remove(); //Remove field html
            x--; //Decrement field counter
        });
    });
```

Here is my html:

```
<div class="field_wrapper">
<div><div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 control-label">Size & Stock <span class="required">*</span></label>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
        <select class="form-control" name="size[]" id="color" required>
            <option>Choose Size</option>
            @foreach ($sizes as $size)
            <option value="{{ $size['id'] }}">{{ $size['name'] }}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="stock[]" id="stock" placeholder="10" required>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add_button" title="Add field">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus red" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:20px;top:6px;"></span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div></div><!-- form-group -->
```

Comment: Hi ,can you show html as well ?

Comment: hi, I have added the html part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your first select-box i.e :`color` is same for all divs you can use `clone()` method to get clone of that select instead of writing laravel code inside jquery code and then pass same to your dynamically generated html code.

Also , inside `remove_button` event you need to use   `$(this).closest(".fieldExtra").remove();` to remove only the div where remove button is clicked.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //get clone of first selectbox
  var slects = $('.outers').find("select").clone();
  var maxField = 10; //Input fields increment limitation
  var addButton = $('.add_button'); //Add button selector
  var wrapper = $('.field_wrapper'); //Input field wrapper
  var fieldHTML = '<div class="fieldExtra"><div class="form-group"><label class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 control-label"></label>'

  fieldHTML += '<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12"><select class="form-control" name="color" id="color" required>"' + $(slects).html() + '"</select></div>' //add same to selct-box
  fieldHTML += '<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="stock" id="stock" placeholder="10" required></div><div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus grey" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:20px"></span></a></div></div><!-- form-group --></div>'; //New input field html
  var x = 1;

  //Once add button is clicked
  $(addButton).click(function() {
    if (x < maxField) {
      x++;
      $(wrapper).append(fieldHTML);
    }
  });

  $(wrapper).on('click', '.remove_button', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest(".fieldExtra").remove(); //get closest fieldExtra remove that 
    x--;
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="field_wrapper">
  <!--added outers class-->
  <div class="outers">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 control-label">Size & Stock <span class="required">*</span></label>
      <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
        <!--dummy selct options-->
        <select class="form-control" name="size[]" id="color" required>
          <option>Choose Size</option>

          <option value="1">X</option>
          <option value="2">Y</option>
          <option value="3">Z</option>

        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="stock[]" id="stock" placeholder="10" required>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add_button" title="Add field">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus red" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:20px;top:6px;"></span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```